# Why does LightInject use an ImmutableHashTree to store registrations, instead of a simple Dictionary?

Tags: c#, binary-search-tree, light-inject

I'm looking at several IoC contains in order to choose one to use in my work, and taking a look at LightInject's codebase I came across something I don't understand...

In ServiceContainer's `GetInstance(Type serviceType, string serviceName)` method, it forms a key from the parameters and calls 'Search' on 'namedDelegates':

```
var key = Tuple.Create(serviceType, serviceName);
var instanceDelegate = namedDelegates.Search(key);
```

namedDelegates is an `ImmutableHashTree<TKey, TValue>`, an internal class that implements (from its own comments):

```
/// A balanced binary search tree implemented as an AVL tree.
```

The reason I'm looking at LightInject is because of its excellent scores in [Daniel Palme's IoC Performance Comparison](http://www.palmmedia.de/blog/2011/8/30/ioc-container-benchmark-performance-comparison) and I'm puzzled as to why a O(log n) binary search algorithm is preferable to using a O(1) Dictionary in this case?

Can anyone educate me here?

Comment: Looking at the source code for `Search(TKey)`, it looks like a dictionary was not used so duplicates could be allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Have not used, just peeked at the source code*

My theory is so that duplicate keys can used as needed either from their API point of view or the consuming dev's. `Search(TKey)` handles checking duplicates it found in the tree so that's what lead me to that.

Another is also probably for performance -- as you mentioned in your question it looks quite speedy. Their search on the `ImmutableHashTree` graciously handles the issue of a value not being found as it just returns `default(TValue)`.

This seems like it would be faster than the following with a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` which already is doing a lot of the same work to find your value based on the Key given.

```
if (myDictionary.ContainsKey(myKey))
    return myDictionary[myKey]; // Practically double the work has been done
else
    return default(TValue);
```

```
try
{
    return myDictionary[myKey];
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // Exceptions can be expensive.
    return default(TValue);
}
```

Their way only does search once and doesn't worry about catching exceptions to handle the fact the key wasn't present.

Again, this is what I gathered giving just a quick look at the source code and should not be considered as concrete.

Comment: That's a really good point. I didn't consider handling not-existent values, which is actually something I've always had problems with also when using Dictionaries in a performant scenario.

Comment: I wonder if there are any significant differences in memory usage?

Comment: Marking this as the answer, since it satisfies my curiosity.